# Is the quantum state fidelity defined as $F(\rho, \sigma)=\text{tr}\sqrt{\rho^{1/2}\sigma\rho^{1/2}}$ or its square?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang, fidelity

I have seen two different definition of Fidelity in different sources. For example, Nielsen & Chuang [QCQI, 10th edition, page 409](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf) defines Fidelity like the following:

$$
F(\rho, \sigma) := \operatorname{tr} \sqrt{\rho^{\frac{1}{2}} \sigma \rho^{\frac{1}{2}}}
$$

An implementation of this definition is also present in this [QETLAB library](http://www.qetlab.com/Fidelity).

Another definition that I have found is:
$$
F(\rho, \sigma) := \Big(\operatorname{tr} \sqrt{\rho^{\frac{1}{2}} \sigma \rho^{\frac{1}{2}}}\Big)^2
$$
This def is present in the highly regarded [Preskill notes](http://www.theory.caltech.edu/%7Epreskill/ph219/chap2_15.pdf) and most other places like [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fidelity_of_quantum_states), [quantiki](https://www.quantiki.org/wiki/fidelity).

Was this definition changed sometime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both definitions are used and authors usually make it clear which one they mean.

Wikipedia also points this out under the [Alternative Defintion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fidelity_of_quantum_states#Alternative_definition) section.