# Is the quantum state fidelity defined as $|\langle\psi|\phi\rangle|$ or $|\langle\psi|\phi\rangle|^2$?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, fidelity

I am reading Preskill's notes on quantum information as well as Chuang's textbook. I saw that fidelity is defined in two different ways in Preskill's notes and Chuang's book. In Preskill's notes, fidelity is defined by **F=|<ψ|φ>|²** whereas **F=|<ψ|φ>|** according to Chuang. I am really confused as to which is the correct definition amongst these two.

Link to Preskill's lecture notes:
[http://theory.caltech.edu/~preskill/ph219/index.html#lecture](http://theory.caltech.edu/%7Epreskill/ph219/index.html#lecture)
Chapter 2, Ex 2.1, 2.2

Comment: Since these are definitions, they cannot be true or false. Do you mean which one is more used? which one is more useful? useful to what?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/11535/55

Comment: @glS Yeah got it, thank you!

Comment: @YaronJarach No I was confused as to why two different definitions are being used for a single quantity.